# Django startapp with custom template unicodeerror

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding

I am getting a strange error when using django startapp command with custom app template. I created a custom app template and there I have a file `models.py` with unicode characters like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
class {{app_name|capfirst}}(models.Model):
    """Toto je text dokumentace. Žluťoučký kůň"""
    pass
```

When I run `python manage.py startapp --template=core/my_app_template application` the `models.py` file does not get proccessed and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/startapp.py", line 25, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle('app', app_name, target, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 162, in handle
    new_file.write(content)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u017d' in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I encode the file so it gets proccessed? I thought `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is enough. Or is there something I should set in the `settings.py`?

I looked at the code and error gets thrown when writing content to the file:

```
with open(new_path, 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(content)
```

So I doubt it's a django's fault.

Comment: If you use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` then you should save the file UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Matthias It's saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Django 1.4. This problem gets solved with Django 1.5. They updated the code and did exactly what catherine suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(new_path, 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(content).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is good, but I think I can't do that without forking django or inheriting the TemplateCommand class and creating my custom command.

Comment: I've tried to fork it. It outputs `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Yep, I've tried. I get another error (oh god): `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: There is maybe the right way to implement it. I don't have more knowledge about it. But try to use encode in other way